# Manhwa where the blonde female lead is killed by her stepbrother during his rebellion

Tags: story-identification, manga

The manhwa starts off with the female lead (FL) running in the castle hallways. Her stepbrother is leading an attack, eliminating all future threats of heirs. During this time, the FL watches her older step-sibling being decapitated by her stepbrother, who has dark hair. The FL tries to reason with her stepbrother, but she’s stabbed regardless.

The FL then regresses back in time and tries to build a bond with her stepbrother, who is viewed as cursed. I recall that she begs her stepbrother to help her study a new language and he agrees to help. In addition, all her other siblings love to torment them.

Anyone have any inkling of the name of this manhwa?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall the names of any places or characters?

Comment: If anyone posts a correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.

Answer (score 1):

Is this ***[The Tyrant's Comfort Doll](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-tyrants-comfort-doll)***...?

> **Legend has it that a man with black hair and red eyes will bring ruin to Den Helder's royal family. Because he was born with these features, Rayton is shunned by the palace as "the cursed one." When the vengeful prince stages a bloody coup detat years later, the powerless youngest princess, Setz, also dies by his sword. Little does Setz know that she's about to wake up in her body five years in the past-- but now that she has, it's her chance to get on Rayton's good side and turn her fate around.** Cracking the prince's cold exterior is a challenge, but once she does, there seems to be no going back! As Rayton grows more and more attached to her, Setz is pulled deeper into the midst of the dark conspiracies brewing around the palace. Has the princess truly escaped death, or is she in more danger than ever before?

Within the Rowaynes -- the ruling family of the Den Helder Empire -- there was a legend that a monster with black hair and red eyes would one day ruin them all. Everyone thought it was just an old wives' tale until Emperor Rowayne the Third fathered an illegitimate son who possessed those very features.  Every other descendant of the Rowayne bloodline had blond hair and blue eyes.

The boy was given the name Rayton -- meaning "the cursed one" -- and the family repeatedly attempted to kill him, but he somehow survived and remained with them, the subject of bullying by the other princes and princesses, with the exception of the female lead, Setz, who was an illegitimate child of the Emperor herself, and thus also looked down upon.

The only person Rayton received any affection from was his mother, a dancer named Liza, but when she was murdered by Setz's mother, Yerna, he snapped, slaughtering everyone in the Imperial Palace, including Setz, whom he caught as she was running down a hallway, subsequently beheading her with his sword.

> [image: The Tyrant's Comfort Doll, chapter 1, page 10.]

Setz then woke up in bed as her twelve-year-old self, five years before her death in the previous timeline, and determined that she needed to win Rayton's favour, and also prevent Yerna from murdering Liza, if possible. In chapter 3, Setz mentioned to Liza that she'd been studying Khazakian, a foreign language, and Liza suggested that Rayton should teach Setz Khazakian, as he was fluent in it.

> [image: The Tyrant's Comfort Doll, chapter 3, page 19.]